# Find and change certain LaTeX coding in vim, using regular expressions?

Tags: vim, regular-expression

How can I change the following LaTeX coding:

```
\cite{1,3-7,9}
```

to

```
\cite{1,3,4,5,6,7,9}
```

in vim? I would prefer to use regular expressions.

Comment: You mean replace it?

Comment: yes . i want to replace it by regular expression

Comment: @sam And you also want it to work on other ranges I suppose? I am not sure if you can do that by using just regular expressions. I think you need a more sophisticated function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use vim's `substitute` command to accomplish this:

```
:%s/\\cite{1,3-7,9}/\\cite{1,3,4,5,6,7,9}/g
```

This will replace all occurrences of `\cite{1,3-7,9}` with `\cite{1,3,4,5,6,7,9}`.

To replace only occurrences that exist on the current line you can use:

```
:s/\\cite{1,3-7,9}/\\cite{1,3,4,5,6,7,9}/g
```

Append `c` if you want vim to ask for confirmation before changing any lines. For example:

```
:%s/\\cite{1,3-7,9}/\\cite{1,3,4,5,6,7,9}/gc
```

Comment: I'm sure he didn't mean the literal `\cite{1,3-7,9}` but anything that matched `\d-\d`

Comment: @Braiam You mean simply expand `3-7`?

Comment: Yeah, if it's 2-5 and 7-10 he wants to expand them too, not just the static 3-7.

Comment: yeah exactly. Braiam said it

Comment: @sam Then I recommend editing your question to clarify that, and checking out [Ingo Karkat's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152050/28893) answer.

Answer (score 2):

To expand any single instance of a range of the form `m-n` within a `\cite{...}` expression, you could perhaps do something like

```
 perl -pe 's/\\cite{(?:\d+,)*\K(\d+)-(\d+)(?=(?:,\d+)*})/sprintf "%s", join(",", ($1..$2))/e' file.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

With my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602), you can restrict `:substitute` commands to pattern matches (`\cite{...}` in your case):

```
:%SubstituteInSearch/\\cite{[^}]\+}/\(\d\+\)-\(\d\+\)/\=join(range(submatch(1),submatch(2)), ',')/g
```

The regular expression parses the start and end numbers, and transforms them into the number range via `join()` and `range()`, using `:help sub-replace-expr`.

Comment: But its is not working in vim

Comment: "SubstituteInSearch" command not found

Comment: @sam Then the plugin (and its dependencies) hasn't been properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Often vim comes with Perl linked.

The possibility of using perl (or similar) in Vim, may by relevant.

When you have `+perl`, you can use `:perldo` + @steeldriver solution (in fact a slightly variation):

```
:perldo s/\\cite{(?:\d+,)*\K(\d+)-(\d+)(?=(,.*?)?})/sprintf "%s",join(",", $1..$2)/e
```